# Can't load context for Test

Tags: java, spring, testing

For some tests, I need to use prod-context and test-context. But Spring can't find my context.

I've tried to put context in a different location, also tried to upload context with various loader.

I have my context in the resources classpath.

```
Entities-src-test-java-Dao-test1
                -resources-META-INF-spring
```

My full path is
`C:\Git\Application\Entities\src\test\resources\META-INF\spring`

When I try, for example

```
public class test1{
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-beans.xml");
...
```

or

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:/C://Git/Application/Entities/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/test-beans.xml")
public class test1{
...
```

Or other various... I got error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [test-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

If I start that class in debugger and check
`System.getProperty("user.dir")` I will see `C:\Git\Application` or `new File(".").getAbsolutePath();` shows me `C:\Git\Application\.`

How to solve that?

Comment: Th path for `@ContextConfiguration` should be `classpath:/META-INF/spring/test-beans.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ,it is not so good to make the location of the configuration file to depend on the file path. Are you sure other teammate will also put the project source codes in the folder `C:\Git\Application\Entities`? If not , your teammate most probably cannot run your test case out of the box , not to mention the build server.

Instead , you can try to refer the configuration file using classpath to prevent such file issues :

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/test-beans.xml")
public class Test{


}
```

And put the `test-beans.xml` inside the folder `C:\Git\Application\Entities\src\test\resources\spring`

Comment: Thank you. It helped me... But why, I don't understand ) And, anywhere, I used file path just to try load context at least somewhere )